# Is Naudio suitable for real time audio processing?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, naudio, naudio-framework

I'm in the process of looking for an audio processing/dsp library.
Thus far the most promising looking one has been the Naudio framework as it is feature rich and has some good learning materials.

I was wondering if anyone here had used Naudio previously and could tell me if it could likely help fulfil these features?

-The Windows application should just run in the background after the user has enabled it.

-Perform dynamic range compression on the fly. Meaning it would need to read small sections of a recording in advance and apply compression before playback. I would assume Naudio's Directsound/WASAPI compatibility could help with this.

-Read input from a microphone while the recording is playing and apply volume adjustments based on microphone input (a form of sidechain compression).

-This audio manipulation shouldn't make any modifications to the actual file, only the playback stream.

The documentation on the github repo (https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) does seem to allude to a lot of this functionality but not much mention of real time.

Comment: It is real-time when the software can keep with the sound card and doesn't add too much noticeable latency.  That was a problem 25 years ago when computers where about 2000x slower than today.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for replying. I'm aware that hardware isn't really a limitation with audio processing these days. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I'm wondering if Naudio has the functionality to easily read and manipulate audio during playback as opposed to manipulating the file. I.e I want to buffer a few seconds of the recording at a time and apply compression before it gets played.